# How do I handle first-stage estimation error in a two-stage simulation?

Tags: r, simulation, monte-carlo

I have a variable $v \sim N(0, 1)$ (i.e., mu=0, sigma=1). Every day I estimate $v$'s interquartile range (IQR). Instead of using the empirical IQR, I estimate $v$'s mu and sigma from 24 hourly observations, then I use the daily estimate of mu and sigma to estimate the daily IQR assuming a normal distribution. I know that $v \sim N(0, 1)$, so this is not unreasonable. Then I use the 30 daily IQR estimates to estimate the monthly variance of the daily IQR estimates.

**Because I know that $v$'s distribution does not change, I should fail to reject that the variance of the daily IQRs is zero. However, my t-test rejects that the variance of the daily IQRs is zero. What am I missing in my simulation? I want to show that the monthly variance of the daily IQR is statistically zero.**

```
ni <- 24 # hours in day
nj <- 30 # days in month
nk <- 60 # months in 5y (so 60 monthly estimates of variance of daily IQR)
n <- ni * nj * nk

i <- rep(seq(ni), length.out=n) # hours
j <- rep(seq(nj), each=ni, length.out=n) # days
k <- rep(seq(nk), each=ni*nj) # months
v <- rnorm(n) # random variable with mean=0, sd=1

x <- data.frame(i, j, k, v)

library(plyr)
library(reshape2)

# returns IQR every day
# mu and sigma based on 24 hourly observations of v
# IQR should be:
# > qnorm(0.75) - qnorm(0.25)
# [1] 1.34898
# by mu and sigma are estimates
fun1 <- function(x) {
  mu <- mean(x$v)
  sigma <- sd(x$v)
  q25 <- qnorm(0.25, mean=mu, sd=sigma)
  q75 <- qnorm(0.75, mean=mu, sd=sigma)
  q75 - q25
}
x1 <- ddply(x, .(j, k), fun1)
head(x1)

# return monthly variance of daily IQR
x2 <- ddply(x1, .(k), function(x) var(x$V1))
head(x2)

# monthly variance of daily IQR _should_ be zero
t.test(x2$V1, mu=0)
```

Here is the output of the `t.test()`. This test *should* fail to reject.

```
> t.test(x2$V1, mu=0)

    One Sample t-test

data:  x2$V1
t = 36.655, df = 59, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.03647219 0.04068421
sample estimates:
mean of x 
0.0385782
```

Comment: Is the sample mean of the sample variance of the IQR definitely theoretically t-distributed? I don't think it can be because the sample variance is always positive, so the t-test isn't appropriate. I don't know if there's a standard test for this.

Comment: @Will--Thanks. Is there a non-standard test for this? Is there a good reference for simulations like this?

Comment: I suppose you could try to find the distribution of your test-statistic and build a test from there? Is this a simplified version of a wider problem or is it just a theoretical exercise? I'm not sure why you would want to test this when you already *know* $v \sim N(0,1)$.

Comment: @Will--In this toy example I know $v \sim N(0,1)$, but in the real problem I estimate $\mu$ and $\sigma$ from data. In a regression, if I estimated an independent variable, then I would bootstrap standard errors. It seems like some sort of similar correction is necessary here. I will check out the distribution of the test statistic. Thanks.